# Flattening a _very_ nesting-intensive function: how to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am the author of [JsonRestStores](https://github.com/mercmobily/JsonRestStores). I have been postponing this issue for a little too long now. Here is a function that would win the "Most stupidly indented function of the year" award.

The main sticky issue is that there is a point where a closure variable is changed:

```
body[ self.idProperty ] = params[ self.idProperty ];
```

There is also an "if" that makes things interesting.

So... is there an *elegant* way to turn this function into something that looks less like an arrow with two pokes? If so, would you be able to provide an example implementation?

```
  _makePostAppend: function( params, body, options, next ){

    var self = this;
    var body;

    if( typeof( next ) !== 'function' ) next = function(){};

    // Check that the method is implemented
    if( ! self.handlePostAppend ){
      self._sendError( next, new self.NotImplementedError( ) );
      return;
    }

    // Check the IDs
    self._checkParamIds( params, body, false, function( err ){  
      self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

        self.schema.validate(  body, function( err, body, errors ) {
          self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

            if( errors.length ){
              self._sendError( next, new self.UnprocessableEntityError( { errors: errors } ) );
            } else {

              // Fetch the doc
              self.execAllDbFetch( params, body, options, function( err, fullDoc ){
                self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){


                  self.extrapolateDoc( params, body, options, fullDoc, function( err, doc) {
                    self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                      self._castDoc( doc, function( err, doc) {
                        self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                          // Actually check permissions
                          self.checkPermissionsPostAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, function( err, granted ){
                            self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                              if( ! granted ){
                                self._sendError( next, new self.ForbiddenError() );
                              } else {

                                // Clean up body from things that are not to be submitted
                                //if( self.schema ) self.schema.cleanup( body, 'doNotSave' );
                                self.schema.cleanup( body, 'doNotSave' );

                                // Paranoid check
                                // Make sure that the id property in the body does match
                                // the one passed as last parameter in the list of IDs
                                body[ self.idProperty ] = params[ self.idProperty ];

                                self.execPostDbAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, function( err, fullDocAfter ){
                                  self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                    self.extrapolateDoc( params, body, options, fullDocAfter, function( err, doc) {
                                      self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                        self._castDoc( fullDocAfter, function( err, docAfter) {
                                          self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                            // Remote request: set headers, and send the doc back (if echo is on)
                                            if( self.remote ){
                                              if( self.echoAfterPostAppend ){

                                                 self.prepareBeforeSend( docAfter, function( err, docAfter ){
                                                   self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                                      self.afterPostAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function( err ){
                                                        self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                                          self._res.json( 200, docAfter );

                                                        });
                                                      });
                                                   })
                                                 })
                                              } else { 

                                                self.afterPostAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function( err ){
                                                  self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                                    self._res.send( 204, '' );

                                                  });
                                                });

                                              }

                                            // Local request: simply return the doc to the asking function
                                            } else {

                                              self.prepareBeforeSend( docAfter, function( err, docAfter ){
                                                self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                                  self.afterPostAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function( err ){
                                                    self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){

                                                      next( null, docAfter, self.idProperty );

                                                    })
                                                  })

                                                })
                                              })
                                            }

                                          })
                                        });

                                      });
                                    })


                                  }) // err
                                }) // execPostDbAppend

                              } // granted


                            })
                          }) 

                        }) 
                      }) 

                    })
                  }) 

                }) // err
              }) // checkPermissionsPostAppend

            } // errors.length

          }) // err
        }) // self.validate

      }) // err
    }) // self.validate
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)? It should be rather straight-forward to implement, but it's still a lot of repetitive labor for anyone to just go through all that code...

Comment: A question about the sync version of the code you wrote (applies here as well): What's with the two variables called "body", one passed to makePostAppend, and one returned from schema.validate? If the two are different, it'd be less confusing if they had different names, and you'd explicitly use "validBody" or whatever afterwards. In general, I'd expect a schema validation type method to not change the body, just return the errors, but maybe that makes sense here.

Comment: validBody would make sense most of the time. However, 1) the "original" body is no longer of ANY use later in the code 2) I like makin validators/object changes that don't change the objects directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was writing code like yours I would prefer to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library and it's [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) function so that I don't have to wrap the asynchronous API with a promise version of it. It's extremely straightforward. Promises are great too and there isn't anything wrong with @Esailija's answer but I personally think this is much easier to implement and is just as readable:

```
var async = require('async');

var _makePostAppend = function (params, body, options, next) {
  var self = this, body;
  if (typeof(next) !== 'function') next = function () { };

  // Check that the method is implemented
  if (!self.handlePostAppend) {
    self._sendError(next, new self.NotImplementedError());
    return;
  }

  async.waterfall([
    function (cb) {
      // Check the IDs
      self.checkParamIds(params, body, false, cb);
    },
    function (cb) {
      self.schema.validate(body, cb);
    },
    function (body, errors, cb) {
      if (errors.length) cb(new self.UnprocessableEntityError({ errors: errors }));
      // Fetch the doc
      self.execAllDbFetch(params, body, options, cb);
    },
    function (fullDoc, cb) {
      self.extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDoc, function (err, doc) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, doc);
      });
    },
    function (fullDoc, doc, cb) {
      self._castDoc(doc, function (err, doc) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, doc);
      });
    },
    function (fullDoc, doc, cb) {
      // Actually check permissions
      self.checkPermissionsPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, function (err, granted) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, doc, granted);
      });
    },
    function (fullDoc, doc, granted, cb) {
      if (!granted) cb(new self.ForbiddenError());

      // Clean up body from things that are not to be submitted
      //if( self.schema ) self.schema.cleanup( body, 'doNotSave' );
      self.schema.cleanup(body, 'doNotSave');

      // Paranoid check
      // Make sure that the id property in the body does match
      // the one passed as last parameter in the list of IDs
      body[self.idProperty] = params[self.idProperty];

      self.execPostDbAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, function (err, fullDocAfter) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, fullDocAfter);
      });
    },
    function (fullDoc, fullDocAfter, cb) {
      self.extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDocAfter, function (err, doc) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, doc, fullDocAfter);
      });
    },
    function (fullDoc, doc, fullDocAfter, cb) {
      self._castDoc(fullDocAfter, function (err, docAfter) {
        cb(err, fullDoc, doc, fullDocAfter, docAfter);
      });
    }
  ], function (err, fullDoc, doc, fullDocAfter, docAfter) {
    self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
      // Remote request: set headers, and send the doc back (if echo is on)
      if (self.remote) {
        if (self.echoAfterPostAppend) {
          async.waterfall([
            function (cb) {
              self.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter, cb);
            },
            function (docAfter, cb) {
              self.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, cb)
            }
          ], function (err, docAfter) {
            self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
                self._res.json(200, docAfter);
            });
          });
        } else {
          self.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function (err) {
            self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
              self._res.send(204, '');
            });
          });
        }

        // Local request: simply return the doc to the asking function
      } else {
        async.waterfall([
          function (cb) {
            self.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter, function (err, docAfter) {
              cb(err, doc, fullDoc, fullDocAfter, docAfter);
            })
          },
          function (doc, fullDoc, fullDocAfter, docAfter, cb) {
            self.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function (err) {
              cb(err, docAfter);
            });
          }
        ], function (err, docAfter) {
          self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
            next(null, docAfter, self.idProperty);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Or better yet, I used the scoping trick from @Esailija's answer:

```
var async = require('async');

var _makePostAppend = function (params, body, options, next) {
  var _self = this, _body, _fullDoc, _doc, _docAfter, _fullDocAfter;
  if (typeof(next) !== 'function') next = function () { };

  // Check that the method is implemented
  if (!_self.handlePostAppend) {
    _self._sendError(next, new _self.NotImplementedError());
    return;
  }

  async.waterfall([
    function (cb) {
      // Check the IDs
      _self.checkParamIds(params, _body, false, cb);
    },
    function (cb) {
      _self.schema.validate(_body, cb);
    },
    function (body, errors, cb) {
      if (errors.length) cb(new _self.UnprocessableEntityError({ errors: errors }));
      // Fetch the doc
      _self.execAllDbFetch(params, body, options, cb);
    },
    function (fullDoc, cb) {
      _fullDoc = fullDoc;
      _self.extrapolateDoc(params, _body, options, fullDoc, db);
    },
    function (doc, cb) {
      _self._castDoc(doc, cb);
    },
    function (doc, cb) {
      _doc = doc;
      // Actually check permissions
      _self.checkPermissionsPostAppend(params, _body, options, doc, _fullDoc, cb);
    },
    function (granted, cb) {
      if (!granted) cb(new _self.ForbiddenError());

      // Clean up body from things that are not to be submitted
      //if( self.schema ) self.schema.cleanup( body, 'doNotSave' );
      _self.schema.cleanup(_body, 'doNotSave');

      // Paranoid check
      // Make sure that the id property in the body does match
      // the one passed as last parameter in the list of IDs
      _body[_self.idProperty] = params[_self.idProperty];

      _self.execPostDbAppend(params, _body, options, _doc, _fullDoc, cb);
    },
    function (fullDocAfter, cb) {
      _fullDocAfter = fullDocAfter;
      _self.extrapolateDoc(params, _body, options, fullDocAfter, cb);
    },
    function (doc, cb) {
      _doc = doc;
      _self._castDoc(_fullDocAfter, cb);
    }
  ], function (err, docAfter) {
    _self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
      // Remote request: set headers, and send the doc back (if echo is on)
      if (_self.remote) {
        if (_self.echoAfterPostAppend) {
          async.waterfall([
            function (cb) {
              _self.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter, cb);
            },
            function (docAfter, cb) {
              _self.afterPostAppend(params, _body, options, _doc, _fullDoc, docAfter, _fullDocAfter, cb)
            },
            function (cb) {
              _self._res.json(200, docAfter);
              cb();
            }
          ], function (err, results) {
            _self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next);
          });
        } else {
          _self.afterPostAppend(params, _body, options, _doc, _fullDoc, docAfter, _fullDocAfter, function (err) {
            _self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
              _self._res.send(204, '');
            });
          });
        }

        // Local request: simply return the doc to the asking function
      } else {
        async.waterfall([
          function (cb) {
            _self.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter, cb);
          },
          function (docAfter, cb) {
            _docAfter = docAfter;
            _self.afterPostAppend(params, _body, options, _doc, _fullDoc, docAfter, _fullDocAfter, cb);
          }
        ], function (err) {
          _self._sendErrorOnErr(err, next, function () {
            next(null, _docAfter, _self.idProperty);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is with wrapping - you can wrap entire APIs with one line, like `var promiseFS = Promise.promisifyAll(fs)`. And some things that are not visible here is for example that with waterfall you have to try-catch anytime there is a possibility for an exception like from JSON.parse. It is really easy to miss that and make your server vulnerable to DoS.

Comment: I didn't say I had a problem. I said I prefer not to do it. I was extremely polite and even complimented your answer. Chill out. You don't have to get all elitist about what choice you made.

Comment: Sorry if it didn't seem that I was chill, I just wanted to know if there is a logical reason not to prefer wrapping.

Comment: The only reason is that I prefer not to wrap the other API. I know it's not hard; I know libraries like Q provide helpers to do it; I just don't prefer it. I prefer to use the async library for dealing with async APIs and promise libraries for dealing with promise APIs. It's just a personal preference, that's all. Also, it's not true that you need to try/catch in waterfall functions. Any thrown exception is caught by async and passed to the final function. https://gist.github.com/chevex/7390400

Comment: Caught by what? There is no try catch in the source code nor domains. See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/A488N/

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I mistakenly thought my result function was being called when I tested it. That is extremely dumb actually. I think this needs a pull-request.

Comment: I found an issue related to just this: https://github.com/caolan/async/pull/396. I believe they are silly for taking that position. I referenced your answer and offered your criticism. Maybe they'll merge the pull request. If this gets rolled in then we'll be back to square one and unless you can provide me another blatant disparity between the two (other than the choice of API) then I still prefer async for async APIs and Q for promise-enabled APIs.

Comment: That is good if they do, but enabling try-catch is just the beginning. Code will still be ugly because then you have to inspect errors because try-catch will swallow everything and you don't want to swallow programmer errors like `TypeError` (and that's when library authors know what they're doing, they usually throw strings or untyped toplevel Error). That's what the `.catch(predicate, fn)` and many other features related to error handling are about :).

Comment: Well how does Q implement such a feature with promises? That still seems like something that could be applied to async and is not inherently unique to promises.

Comment: Yes I didn't mean it can only be done with promises but that there is more work to it than what the pull request is doing. Well, Q doesn't implement such a feature, the library I am using is bluebird.

Comment: Gotcha, well in that case then it just sounds like some libraries need to be improved and that both styles for dealing with callback hell are useful. It's just a matter of preference. I just like async because the callback-style is still clearly visible, very little is abstracted away while still flattening the nest. If an API supports both styles (such as mongoose, angular, etc) or I am writing my own API then I am on your side and I prefer to use promises.

Comment: That's cool, I am just always on the lookout to improve from feedback etc :)

Comment: If you want another example of a place where I prefer async over promises, I think it makes tests very readable when dealing with callbacks. Though here I was able to use `async.series` instead of `waterfall`. https://github.com/chevex/mongoose-auto-increment/blob/master/test/test.js

Comment: I just marked this answer as the correct one, as it's a flat-ification of my function without making a small revolution in the way it's written. I think the "scoping trick" (as we call it now) is really good and will help people on SO in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I don't know if it really needs a name as it's just simply putting the variables in a higher scope so as to prevent the need to pass them around. It's a common technique, just probably not so obvious when staring at callback hell.

Answer (score 2):

Promises allow you to write async code pretty much directly from sync code because they restore exception bubbling and return value composition.

Assuming you have already rewritten the other methods to promises:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

...

_makePostAppend: function (params, body, options) {
  var fullDoc, doc, docAfter, fullDocAfter;
  // Check that the method is implemented
  if (!this.handlePostAppend) {
    return Promise.rejected(new this.NotImplementedError());
  }

  //Note that it is Promise#bind, not Function#bind
  return this._checkParamIds(param, body, false).bind(this).then(function () {
    return this.schema.validate(body);
  }).then(function () {
    return this.execAllDbFetch(params, body, options);
  }).then(function (_fullDoc) {
    fullDoc = _fullDoc;
    return this.extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDoc);
  }).then(function (doc) {
    return this._castDoc(doc);
  }).then(function (_doc) {
    doc = _doc;
    return this.checkPermissionsPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc);
  }).then(function (granted) {
    if (!granted) throw new this.ForbiddenError();

    this.schema.cleanup(body, 'doNotSave');
    body[this.idProperty] = params[this.idProperty];
    return this.execPostDbAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc);
  }).then(function (_fullDocAfter) {
    fullDocAfter = _fullDocAfter;
    return this.extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDocAfter);
  }).then(function (doc) {
    return this._castDoc(fullDoc);
  }).then(function (_docAfter) {
    docAfter = _docAfter;
    if (this.remote) {
      if (this.echoAfterPostAppend) {
        return this.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter).bind(this).then(function (_docAfter) {
          docAfter = _docAfter;
          return this.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter);
        }).then(function () {
          return this._res.json(200, docAfter);
        });
      } else {
        return this.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter).bind(this).then(function () {
          return this._res.send(204, '');
        });
      }
    } else {
      return this.prepareBeforeSend(docAfter).then(function (_docAfter) {
        docAfter = _docAfter;
        return this.afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Note that you no longer need to cheat with 2-space indentation, the above would be more readable with 4 space indentation. Maybe that's just me.

Usage would be:

```
this._makePostAppend(params, body, options).bind(this).then(function() {

}).catch(this.UnprocessableEntityError, function(e) {

}).catch(this.NotImplementedError, function(e) {

}).catch(this.ForbiddenError, function(e) {

}).catch(function(e) {
  //Any other error
});
```

Comment: Wow. This is the first answer I see on SO to the "indentation problem" where you _actually_ solve the problem for real. I loved the way you dealt with the scoping of the variables. The only thing I don't quite like is fact that my original code is a little easier to follow, but I assume that's because of what I am used to.

Answer (score 1):

Callback hell is a scary place :)

You could use something like [Step.js](https://github.com/creationix/step) which makes callbacks a more readable sequence of steps.  There are many other async management libs out there too, but I'm not sure that will really save you here... You'll still have a jumbled mess, it just won't be indented quite so heavily.

---

I suggest you stop thinking procedurally, and start thinking about your data model, what objects have what methods, and what methods are responsible for what atomic tasks.

So I would simply refactor in the same way I would any overly obese method: by abstracting bits of related code into their own methods.

```
self.checkIds(function() {
  self.fetchDoc(function() {
    self.checkPermissions({
      deny: self.denyPermission,
      allow: function() {
        // call method that handles the next thing
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Now you have a macro method that simply calls component methods where the real work happens.  Each of these methods may internally have a few callbacks, and then invoke whatever "all done" callback you give it, passing control back to your macro function.

This has the added benefit of being able to read and understand this large number of steps based on what it actually happening.  It reads like step by step instructions now, instead a ginormous pile of low level noise.

So make a dozen much smaller methods, that do a small set of very simple asynchronous things and callback when done.  And be sure to name them descriptively.  Then link them all together in a smaller and more maintainable tree of callbacks.

If this big method can make sense without comments, you'll know your pretty close to a much better version.

Good luck, you have your work cut out for you with this one.

---

Note that you also have some common patterns, so your repeating yourself!

Like here:

```
self.extrapolateDoc( params, body, options, fullDocAfter, function( err, doc) {
  self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){
```

And here:

```
self.afterPostAppend( params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter, function( err ){
  self._sendErrorOnErr( err, next, function(){
```

You could write a method that accepts a method name and an argument list, and automatically shoves stuff through `self._sendErrorOnErr()` when the first method callsback.

Find more common patterns and you could trim this down even more.

Answer (score -2):

This one is a bit of a cheaty non-answer, but hopefully at least a tiny bit illuminating. The first thing I would do is simplify the synchronous version of the code itself.  You start with something like this:

```
_makePostAppend: function (params, body, options) {
  // ...and in the darkness, bind them (if needed)
  _.bindAll(this, 'checkParamIds', 'execAllDbFetch'); // ...etc.
  // Shortcuts. These would be unnecessary for private methods in a closure
  var
    checkParamIds = this.checkParamIds,
    schema = this.schema,
    execAllDbFetch = this.execAllDbFetch,
    execPostDbAppend = this.execPostDbAppend,
    extrapolateDoc = this.extrapolateDoc,
    checkPermissionsPostAppend = this.checkPermissionsPostAppend,
    _castDoc = this._castDoc,
    UnprocessableEntityError = this.UnprocessableEntityError,
    ForbiddenError = this.ForbiddenError,
    idProperty = this.idProperty,
    remote = this.remote,
    echoAfterPostAppend = this.echoAfterPostAppend,
    prepareBeforeSend = this.prepareBeforeSend,
    afterPostAppend = this.afterPostAppend,
    _res = this._res;

  checkParamIds(params, body, false);

  // This could throw the UnprocessableEntityError itself
  var errors = schema.validate(body);
  if (errors.length) {
    throw new UnprocessableEntityError({ errors: errors });
  }

  // Every method takes params+body+options. Wrap that in a single object? Alternatively:
  // var processor = this.getDocProcessor(params, body, options);
  // var fullDoc = processor.execAllDbFetch();
  // var doc = extrapolateDoc(fullDoc);
  // ...etc.
  var fullDoc = execAllDbFetch(params, body, options);
  var doc = extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDoc);
  doc = _castDoc(doc);

  // This could throw the ForbiddenException itself
  var granted = checkPermissionsPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc);
  if (!granted) { throw new ForbiddenError(); }

  schema.cleanup(body, 'doNotSave');
  body[idProperty] = params[idProperty];

  var fullDocAfter =  execPostDbAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc);
  var docAfter =  extrapolateDoc(params, body, options, fullDocAfter);
  docAfter = _castDoc(docAfter);

  if (!remote || echoAfterPostAppend) {
    docAfter = prepareBeforeSend(docAfter);
  }
  afterPostAppend(params, body, options, doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter);
  return remote ?
    _res.json(200, echoAfterPostAppend ? docAfter : '') :
    docAfter;
}
```

Now, if you have generators, you can simply prefix the async methods with yield, then pass it to whatever library function that does the rest (Q.star, I think is one). You'll need to promisify the async methods, or at the very least bind their inputs (i.e. func(in1, in2) becomes apply(func, in1, in2)), but that way you end up with something that looks very similar to plain old synchronous code.

Chances are you don't have generators, though, so have a less cheaty answer as well. Less cheaty means I'm starting from a slightly simplified variant, as described in the notes above. That is to say, the synchronous code looks like this:

```
// Helper method. Could be private, defined elsewhere, etc.
var extrapolateCast = function (fullDoc) {
  var doc = extrapolateDoc(fullDoc);
  return _castDoc(doc);
};

_makePostAppend: function (params, body, options) {
  checkParamIds(params, body, false);
  schema.validate(body);
  var proc = getDocProcessor(params, body, options);

  var fullDoc = proc.execAllDbFetch();
  var doc = extrapolateCast(fullDoc);

  proc.checkPermissionsPostAppend(doc, fullDoc);

  schema.cleanup(body, 'doNotSave');
  body[idProperty] = params[idProperty];

  var fullDocAfter =  proc.execPostDbAppend(doc, fullDoc);
  var docAfter =  extrapolateCast(fullDocAfter);

  if (!remote || echoAfterPostAppend) {
    docAfter = prepareBeforeSend(docAfter);
  }
  proc.afterPostAppend(doc, fullDoc, docAfter, fullDocAfter);
  return remote ?
    _res.json(200, echoAfterPostAppend ? docAfter : '') :
    docAfter;
}
```

Twenty lines or so, a lot more managable. With async, one solution using a context object could look like this. (Yes, I know this is kind of terrible in many ways, but I've spent a lot of time on this already.)
EDIT: This wouldn't actually work, variables from the context would be resolved immediately, not just before execution. You could wrap them in a function to make it deferred, or implement a 'load' function analogous to 'save'.

```
_makePostAppend: function (params, body, options) {
  // Helper method. Could be private, defined elsewhere, etc.
  var extrapolateCast = pipeline(
    extrapolateDoc,
    _castDoc
  );

  var vars = {},
    contextObj = context(vars),
    save = contextObj.save,
    record = contextObj.record,
    proc = getDocProcessor(params, body, options);

  pipeline(
    apply(checkParamIds, params, body, false),
    apply(schema.validate, body),
    record('fullDoc', proc.execAllDbFetch),
    save('doc', extrapolateCast),
    apply(proc.checkPermissionsPostAppend, vars.doc, vars.fullDoc),
    apply(schema.cleanup, body, 'doNotSave'),
    lift(function () { body[idProperty] = params[idProperty]; }),
    record('fullDocAfter', apply(proc.execPostDbAppend, vars.doc, vars.fullDoc)),
    record('docAfter', extrapolateCast),
    conditional(
      function () { return !remote || echoAfterPostAppend; },
      prepareBeforeSend
    ),
    apply(proc.afterPostAppend, vars.doc, vars.fullDoc, vars.docAfter, vars.fullDocAfter)
  );

  // NOTE: Converting this part is left as an exercise for the reader. (read: I'm tired.)
  return remote ?
    _res.json(200, echoAfterPostAppend ? docAfter : '') :
    docAfter;
};
```

The helper methods you see below:

```
var 
context = function (store) {
  return {
    save: function (key, task) {
      return pipeline(
        task,
        tap(lift(function (result) {
          store[key] = result;
        }))
      );
    },
    // Same as save, but discards result
    record: function (key, task) {
      return pipeline(
        task,
        liftM(function (result) {
          store[key] = result;
          return [];
        })
      );
    }
  };
},
conditional = function (cond, task) {
  // NOTE: Too tired to figure this out now. Sorry!
},
createTask = function (impl) {
  return function () {
    var args = _.initial(arguments),
      callback = _.last(arguments);
    async.nextTick(function () {
      impl.call(null, args, callback);
    });
  };
},
liftM = function (fun) {
  return createTask(function (args, callback) {
    try {
      var results = fun.apply(this, args);
      return callback.apply(this, [null].concat(results));
    } catch (err) {
      return callback.call(this, err);
    }
  });
},
lift = function (fun) {
  return createTask(function (args, callback) {
    try {
      var result = fun.apply(this, args);
      return callback(null, result);
    } catch (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
  });
},
tap = function (interceptor) {
  return createTask(function (args, callback) {
    return async.waterfall([
      _.partialArr(interceptor, args),
      liftM(function () {
        return args;
      })
    ], callback);
  });
};
```